# Duplicate ACK and TCP Retransmissions

Tags: linux, vpn, tcpdump, aix

I'm doing some scp transfers between an AIX and a Linux in two separated LAN (I have a VPN between them).

Sometimes the connection ends well, so I get 50MB/s. In many other cases, instead, the connections starts fast and then drops until it ends with a low throughput, around 4-5 MB/s.

These are the test I made (file dimension: 1GB)

[SCP transfers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtN4F.png)

As you can see, there's some cases where my connection is very low.

I made some tcpdump AIX-side and I found lots of DupACK and TCP Retransmissions. This is my dump seen from the AIX: [Dump AIX to Linux (VPN)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ko4k3w_NKjcQE_LDht_8qae8y_Rqodda)

Could you help me understand what is wrong?

I made also a dump from the firewall. Let me know if this may help

Thank you :)

Comment: You probably have congestion somewhere between the networks that causes packet loss.

Comment: How can I understand what is causing this congestion? Thanks

Comment: Congestion happens all the time. You will need to look at all the routers between the two networks.